# Drawing the VLSI circuit

Tags: vlsi

[image]

If I want to draw this type of picture 
which program should I use?

Just for drawing not for some technical things.

Comment: Are you asking for a tool to make a mask set for VLSI design, or just to make a technical illustration? For illustrations, I just use whatever is the best vector graphics editor on the computer, which when I'm not on my home computer is usually PowerPoint (unfortunately).

Comment: In any event, the answer will be heavily based on opinion and you don't want to hear my opinion of Powerpoint. There are a number of VLSI design programs and recommendations will again be opinions. I don't think this question is appropriate for EE.SE.

Comment: And why exactly would you want to draw this for a not-technical "thing"?

Answer (score 3):

There are several tools to create VLSI designs: most of them are commercial and cost quite some money, like [Cadence Virtuoso](http://www.cadence.com/products/cic/pages/default.aspx) or [Synopsys](http://www.synopsys.com/home.aspx). And what is more expensive are the libraries for the process technology nodes, usually provided by foundries.

But there are also some open source ones, like [Electric](http://www.staticfreesoft.com/productsFree.html). You find more software for Electronic design at [this page](http://www.prototypexpress.com/design/software.htm) or [this](http://www.vlsitechnology.org/html/ic_software.html). But I suppose that, as for commercial software, you might need technology-specific libraries that may not be available for some of these tools.

Comment: not the tool for create the VLSI. just for drawing like above for report paper

Comment: You mean to look exactly like the one above?

Comment: it does not have to exactly but exactly from cadence kind of not pretty